# CSS Inline Scroll only

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, web

For each article added to the contatiner div, "inlineExample", the goal is that they load to the right and there is no vertical overflow but dynamically the css can handle each additional article added to the right.

```
<div id="inlineExample">
    <article>block 1</article> 
    <article>block 2</article>
    <article>block 3</article>
    <article>block 4</article>
</div>
```

Goal would be

block1 block2 block 3 block4

all inline with overflow in the X direction, with none below in the Y direction. Jsfiddle of example:
http://jsfiddle.net/fmbe6/

Any solution is welcome I am currenlt developing in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: do you want it to be like this??[link](http://jsfiddle.net/fmbe6/)

Comment: That is the same link I supplied. To edit/update jsfiddle to a new url click the save button.

Comment: sorry:) [link](http://jsfiddle.net/fmbe6/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/fmbe6/4/

Namely: for your article, you want:

```
article {
    /* other properties */
    display: inline-block; /* not float */
}

.container {
    overflow-x: scoll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

css property overflow: auto or scroll;

Comment: I think that's still not enough. In addition to an overflow property, you should be using `white-space: nowrap` and probably `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left`.

Comment: he can do in both ways like make one div and define width to 100% then make width fix for all article like if there are 4 then width:25% and float left then all will be one line or         as you said display inline and if he want to make scroll visible to one side only then use overflow-x:hidden or overflow-y:hidden tht will make achive his goal

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fmbe6/8/)

Change your CSS to:

```
#inlineExample {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#inlineExample>article {
    display:inline-block;
}
```